# Errors when connecting "wavecom fasttrack" to tcp/ip or http

Tags: http, tcp, ip, gsm, at-command

These AT commands give errors:

```
1-AT+CGDCONT?
2-AT+WIPCFG=1   //start IP stack , wiplib was't downloaded and I searched a lot but without any benefit.
```

3-how can I download wiplib libary ?

4-ATD*99#   or  ATD&99***1#   give:

```
CONNECT  115200  then garbage   then  NON CARRIER
```

I searched a lot , but I didn't find the Solution .

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

The "garbage" you get after `CONNECT 115200` is binary [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) traffic where the modem tries to establish a PPP connection with the computer. When there is noting on the computer that responds to this, the modem times out and prints `NO CARRIER`.

You need to send the AT commands through a dialer program that is capable of establishing a PPP connection.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer :).
I don't want the computer connect to the network , I need the mobile to start tcp/ip connection.
and I don't know these AT commands which you mention.